# Listbox Item Template for an empty list

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a list box with an item template defined in XAML like this:

```
        <ListBox Name="listBoxDisruptions">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="29">Hello! some item</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>             

        </ListBox>
```

Now what i want is to display a line of text in the center of the listbox in case the ItemSource for this listbox is empty.

Does XAML support some kind of no item template, ? something like this:

```
    <ListBox Name="listBoxDisruptions">

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="29">Hello! some item</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 

<ListBox.NoItemTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="No Items to display"/>
</ListBox.NoItemTemplate>                   

            </ListBox>
```

So ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be a XAML way to do it using WPF-like techniques - [Listbox Item Template for an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337557/listbox-item-template-for-an-empty-list)

However, in Overflow7 I got bored trying to make these work - so I used a slightly-hacky trick instead of adding an extra TextBlock to the page and then using:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
            listBox1.ItemsSource = data; 

            data.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(data_CollectionChanged); 

        } 

        void data_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) { 
            if (data.Count == 0) 
                textBlock1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
            else 
                textBlock1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
        }
```

(Trick learnt from http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/70755/431687.aspx)

Comment: well I could have done this, but it feels strange that Silverlight doesn't have something like this.

Comment: I do something similar, but I just have a CollectionLengthToVisibility converter that I use to hide / show things based on collection length.

Comment: The link on first line links to this page.

Answer (score 2):

You could take the textblock outside of the listview, and then bind the visibility of the textblock to the count of the list your using for the listview, using a converter.

EDIT: Example as asked for:-

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <Grid/>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<TextBlock Text="Some text" Visibility="{Binding MyItemSource.Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Declare the converter either in your page resources, or a resource dictionary in your app like so:

```
<converters:CountToVisibilityConverter x:Key="CountToVisibilityConverter" />
```

and then the converter could be:

```
public sealed class CountToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var i = (Int32)value;

            if (i > 0)
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            else
                return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        return new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any example of your suggestion?